# error reading first path in the walk /protos Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/protos' with Firestore and Typescript lambda

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, lambda, firebase-admin

I have the following code which communicates with Firestore:

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import serviceAccount from './reformma-firebase-adminsdk.json'

const params = {
    type: serviceAccount.type,
    projectId: serviceAccount.project_id,
    privateKeyId: serviceAccount.private_key_id,
    privateKey: serviceAccount.private_key,
    clientEmail: serviceAccount.client_email,
    clientId: serviceAccount.client_id,
    authUri: serviceAccount.auth_uri,
    tokenUri: serviceAccount.token_uri,
    authProviderX509CertUrl: serviceAccount.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
    clientC509CertUrl: serviceAccount.client_x509_cert_url
  }

export const getOrder = async () => {
    admin.initializeApp({
        credential: admin.credential.cert(params),
        databaseURL: "https://reformma-ee9b3.firebaseio.com"
    });

    let db = admin.firestore();
    db.collection('orders').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });

      return "helooooooooo"
};
```

However I get some errors when I try to make the `get()`:

> error reading first path in the walk /protos
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/protos'

Comment: Can you check the version of `@google-cloud/firestore` installed with your function?